# How to extract numbers from a string and add to an array?

Tags: php, regex, split, preg-match-all, regex-lookarounds

I want to convert this string:

```
<5> 20825.24 </ 5> <7> 0.0 </ 7> <8> 0.0 </ 8>
```

to an array with key value

I would really appreciate the help

I tried different xmlParse strategies but it is not exactly an xml.

```
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement("<5>20825.24</5><7>0.0</ 7><8>0.0</8>");
```

Response: String could not be parsed as XML

I expect an array like this:

```
[5=>20825.24,7=>0.0,8=>0.0]
```

Comment: XML tag names cannot start with a number, so this means unless you process the data - it isn't valid XML (also doesn't have a root node - but that's easily fixed)

Answer (score 3):

As long as your output has numbers at the start of the XML tag name, it won't be valid XML.  You may have to resort to using a regex to do the job.

This uses `<(\d*)>(.*?)</~` which looks for a `<` followed by digits, then the `>` and captures everything up till the next `</`.  It then combines the values from capture group 1 (the tag name) and 2 (the value)...

```
$data = "<5>20825.24</5><7>0.0</ 7><8>0.0</8>";

preg_match_all("~<(\d*)>(.*?)</~", $data, $matches);
$output = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
print_r($output);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [5] => 20825.24
    [7] => 0.0
    [8] => 0.0
)
```

Comment: That's concise, and much cleaner than my ans.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$subject = '<5> 20825.24 <7> 0.0 <8> 0.0';
$pattern = '/\<(\d)\>\s+(\d+\.\d+)/u';
$result = preg_match_all($pattern,$subject,$output);

$numbers = $output[1];
$output = $output[2];
$outTotal = [];

foreach ($numbers as $key => $number) {
    $outTotal[$number] = $output[$key];
}
var_dump($outTotal);
```

gives:

```
array(3) {
  [5]=>
  string(8) "20825.24"
  [7]=>
  string(3) "0.0"
  [8]=>
  string(3) "0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can also use a regular expression and collect our desired numbers, then push it to a new array:

```
(?:<)(\d?)(?:>)(?:.+?)([0-9.]+)?
```

This expression might also work with [nested elements](https://regex101.com/r/hXouPx/1).

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?:<)(\d?)(?:>)(?:.+?)([0-9.]+)?/m';
$str = '<5> 20825.24 </ 5> <7> 0.0 </ 7> <8> 0.0 </ 8>';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

$arr = array();
foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$value[1]] = $value[2];
}

var_dump($arr);
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [5]=>
  string(8) "20825.24"
  [7]=>
  string(3) "0.0"
  [8]=>
  string(3) "0.0"
}
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/d0gDa3/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the digits in the opening tag with the digits in the closing tag, you could use a regex make use of a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) to the first capturing group:

```
<(\d+)>\h*\d+(?:\.\d+)?\h*</\h*\1>
```

**Explanation**

- `<` Match `>` char
- `(\d+)>` Capture in group 1 matching 1+ digits and match `>`
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits followed by an optional part to match a dot and 1+ digits
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `<` Match `<`
- `/\h*` Match `\` followed by 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `\1>` Match backreference to group 1 using `\1` and match `>`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OTJBkv/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/umJkl)

For example:

```
$re = '~<(\d+)>\h*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\h*</\h*\1>~m';
$str = '<5> 20825.24 </ 5> <7> 0.0 </ 7> <8> 0.0 </ 8>';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [5] => 20825.24
    [7] => 0.0
    [8] => 0.0
)
```

Note that now the array keys are 5, 7 and 8. Keep in mind that if you might use different data, that arrays can not have duplicate keys.